# Hide the border between two combined cells in TableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

I have 4x4 table. How to make that the first row will have 2 cells only?
Tried with `ColumnSpan` but it's still drawing borders between cells.

Example:

```
----------------------
|   A     |      B   |
----------------------
| 1  |  2 |  3  |   4|
----------------------
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `Dock` a `Panel` with `Margin=0` in a cell and then span that `Panel` to the desired size and use it as the container of the objects in the cell.

Alternatively, you can set `AutoSize` of a `Label` to `false` and then set its `Dock` to `Fill` and then span that `Label` to the desired size.

(The Panel is shown in Green, the Labels are shown in Yellow)

[image]

The only problem when using borders with 2 pixels width (like inset) is it makes one pixel to appear at the top. This can be avoided using 1-pixel wide border type (like Single)

Comment: I dragged lebel from Toolbox,  set merge 0,0,0,0,  Can you write rest steps?

Comment: @ILyaShapira, drag a Panel from Toolbox, select it, click on the small arrow button on the top right of the panel and select Dock in parent container. Then drag your label onto the panel

Comment: @ILyaShapira I also updated my answer. please see it again

Comment: I dragged Panel, Docked to parent container, set merge, set Columnspan to 2, it expended, but borders still appear

Comment: @ILyaShapira what is the BackColor of the Panel?

Comment: Aquamarine color

Comment: @ILyaShapira I'm out of ideas. clearly, there is some crucial information missing from your question.

Comment: I need it exactly like you did on your picture

Comment: @ILyaShapira here's the source code: https://www.dropbox.com/s/colw6k9i7l502q3/WindowsFormsApplication1.zip?dl=0

Comment: We borders of the area is now bolded, i can move Label to second cell, but it still has old cell lines between

Comment: @ILyaShapira how do you mean? can u clarify?

Comment: I will try to understand from your file you uploaded

Comment: @ILyaShapira ok I re-uploaded the file using the exact code in the picture

Comment: You are almost there. @ILyaShapira You should set margin of the panels to `0` as already mentioned in the answer, but you probably overlooked.

Comment: It didn't work because i didn't coloured the little panel. Now it's work. Thank you very much for help and thank you that you uploaded the file. I can't vote up you up bcs my rating still under 15

Comment: You can accept the answer by click on the checkmark at left side of the answer. Make it green.

Comment: @ILyaShapira glad to help. please read the comment above.

Comment: Sry i'm new here. Do you mean arrows on left side? (Up Down)

Comment: @ILyaShapira yes, just below those arrays there is a tick symbol. click it to inform other users that this question is solved

Comment: You can also take a [tour] to learn.