# How to Remove border in cell of TableLayoutPanel in winform?

Tags: c#

I want to clear a bit border in cell of tablelayoutpabel, but i can't find it. 
[this is my tablelayoutpanel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08FgB.png)
i tried to insert panel children into.
[i want to remove the border in red circles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpn6m.png)

Comment: [Hide the border between two combined cells in TableLayoutPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53923078/hide-the-border-between-two-combined-cells-in-tablelayoutpanel)

Comment: i'm done, thank you